# How is an Intent Service Declared in the Android Manifest?

Tags: android, service, android-manifest, intentservice

Straight forward question:

Is an IntentService declared in the Android Manifest as a regular service, or is there another way? It tried searching for it, but I couldn't find the answer.

Here is the regular Service declaration:

```
 <service
                android:name=".NameOfService">
 </service>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In your manifest you declare a service with `android:name=".Communication"`, this means that your service class should be located in `com.exercise.AndroidClient.Communication`

Check that the packages are correct. Note that the "." (dot) refers to the root of your package (ie the package declared in the manifest). So, for example, if your package is `com.exercise.AndroidClient` and your service class is under `com.exercise.AndroidClient.services.Communication` you need to declare the service like this:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".services.Communication" />
```

Or specify the full package:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.exercise.AndroidClient.services.Communication" />
```

Comment: how to declare local service in manifest e.g. activity class name is "TestActivity" and "MyService" inside this class.

Comment: What's `enabled` for?

Comment: enabled, according to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html, is whether or not the service can be instantiated by the system — "true" if it can be, and "false" if not. The default value is "true".

Answer (score 16):

Nothing different same as a regular one

Here is mine

```
<service android:name=".MyIntentService" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:enabled="true"/>
```

If yours is not working try something like

```
<service android:name="com.my.qualified.MyIntentService" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:enabled="true"/>
```

**EDIT**

When you go to settings >> application >> running services
the list of running services will be displayed.

The **android:icon** will be **thumb image**

and **androin:label** will be the **display text**

Comment: What does declaring an icon for it do? And what does the enabled tag mean?

Comment: Explanations can be found here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html