# Why a Null Pointer when trying to use Android Local Bound Service?

Tags: android, service

In the Service class:

```
class AeroBluetoothService extends Service { ...
private final IBinder asBleBinder = new LocalBinder();
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    AeroBluetoothService getService() {
        return AeroBluetoothService.this;
    } 
} 

@Override 
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return asBleBinder; 
}
```

In the client Activity:

```
Intent bindAsBleIntent;

@Override
public void onServiceConnected( ComponentName className, IBinder service ) {
    AeroBluetoothService.LocalBinder asBleBinder = (AeroBluetoothService.LocalBinder) service;
    asBleServiceRef = asBleBinder.getService();
}
```

In Client's onCreate():

```
bindAsBleIntent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), AeroBluetoothService.class );
bindService( bindAsBleIntent, /*ServiceConnection*/ this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE );
```

The problem is that when I try to call a Service method from the Client:

```
asBleServiceRef.scanForAero();
```

the reference to the Service instance, `asBleServiceRef`, is `null`. It is as though the `onServiceConnected()` callback is not being called (or is passing a null argument).

I copied this code quite carefully from an Android example. I just noticed that the example calls `bindService()` from its `onStart()` method, whereas I'm calling from `onCreate()`. Could that make any difference? What's the problem?

Comment: post logcat output here

Comment: Post the Activity class code, did you declare the service in Manifest ?

Comment: Bingo! Forgot all about the Manifest. I will research & add.

Comment: refer this to add service in manifest http://stackoverflow.com/a/7145022/6478047

Comment: Also noted that the Service class must be public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @avinash correctly saw, the problem was simply neglecting to declare the Service in the Manifest.