# why intent service doesn't start?

Tags: android

i have the following intent service :

```
public class BackGround extends IntentService {

    Handler mhandler;
    final static String NAME = "BackGround";
    public BackGround(String name) {
        super(NAME);
        mhandler = new Handler();
    }
    public  BackGround(){
        super(NAME);
        mhandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
       Log.d("message","in intent service");//i don't get this message
    }
}
```

and this is how i start it in MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,BackGround.class);
startService(intent);
```

intent service doesn't start, i don't see the log message.

Comment: Have you make an entry of `BackGround` Intent Service in manifest ?

Comment: what do you see on the `logcat` window?

Comment: @ADM no i did not, how can i do that?

Comment: `<service name=".Background"></Service>`. Or use fully qualified name with package name .See [How is an Intent Service Declared in the Android Manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144908/how-is-an-intent-service-declared-in-the-android-manifest)

Comment: before doing anything, read [Services overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Comment: @ADM Thanks, it worked